# Finding Prime numbers from 1 to 300 in C

Tags: c, primes

I have typed the following program in C language:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int i = 1, a = 2;
    while (i <= 300)
    {
        while (a < i)
        {
            if (i % a == 0)
                break;
            else
                printf ("%d\n", i);
            a++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program is printing many non-prime values too like `295`, `275`, etc...
Please help, I'm a beginner and lacks much experience.

Comment: reset `a` to 2 for each number

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). And learn *right now* how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb` on Linux); it is a skill that will be useful all your programming life.

Comment: also printing the number each time you find a non-divisor is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Beside the fact that you're not resetting `a` to 2, the `printf()` statement is not placed correctly. This will print *any* number of `i` that cannot be divided by 2 (even if it can be divided by another number).

Change your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int i = 1, a = 2, is_prime;
    while (i <= 300)
    {
        is_prime = 1;

        while (a < i)
        {
              if (i % a == 0) {
                is_prime = 0;
                break;
              }

              a++;
        }

        if(is_prime)
          printf ("%d\n", i);

        a = 2;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a back to 2 before you enter the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int i = 1, a = 2;
    while (i <= 300)
    {
        a = 2; // add this line
        while (a < i)
        {
                if (i % a == 0)
                break;
                else
                printf ("%d\n", i);
                a++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your method isn't very fast. You should read this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Also in line `int i = 1, a = 2;` assigning value `2` to `a` now not required.

Comment: This answer fixes a first issue, but as mentioned by bolov in the comment above, you should print `i` only if no `a` less than `i` divides `i`, not for each non-divisor of `i`, otherwise any odd number will be displayed at least once.